# Typo3 extension for Facebook-like posting and commenting system

Tags: facebook, typo3

This is not (!) a question about Facebook Like buttons!

I am searching for a Typo3 extension which allows Facebook-like posting and commenting with following requirements:

- posts in order of creation
- small comments just underneath
- inline editing for posts and comments (not at the bottom of the site or anything like that
- small avatars aside
- everything should work like this Facebook status comments — or whatever it is called — simple, inline and intuitive.

Comment: disqus not being an option?

Comment: I am not sure what disqus is about – it is implemented as an iframe, and it seems to be part of a centralized system… I would be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that that the extension `dialog` comes close to you needs: http://fedext.net/overview/extensions/frontend-plugins.html

I am not sure about the inline edit part, but this should be easily achievable with some JS magic.

Comment: My Typo3 6.1.4 broke after installing the extension with all it's dependencies. The main area in the back-end is now just grey, with no information on it. And I do not even know how to resolve this issue now.

Comment: You can remove extensions directly in the ``typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`` if you remove all files and folders from ``typo3temp/Cache``. Anyway, you should follow those advices to get more information: http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2009/03/blank-empty-page-in-typo3.html

Comment: I tried Dimitry Dulepov's suggestions, but it did not change anything. Typo3 still [shows nothing](http://formiculare.org/typo3error/) in back-end. Do you have any idea, why such an error could appear?

Comment: It can be any PHP error or just as misconfigured webserver. You will need to check the error logs.

Answer (score -1):

I think this looks nice: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/facebook_socialplugins

You have so much requirements so think about developing an own extension for your Stuff.

Comment: He stated that it is not about facebook buttons, but rather about a real plugin.